# How to Set GraphQL Endpoint in GatsbyJS

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I'm  trying my hand  at GraphQL with GatsbyJS. I am having issues figuring out how to configure the GraphQL endpoint for my GatsbyJS application to query from.

I  keep getting errors that my queries cannot be found:

> If you don't expect "pages" to exist on the type "Query" it is most likely a typo.
> However, if you expect "pages" to exist there are a couple of solutions to common problems:

Here is my [GatsbyJS repo](https://github.com/davinaleong/proj-the-beloveds-blog). Go to the **development** branch to view the code.

This is the [GraphQL endpoint](http://davinas-cms.herokuapp.com/graphql) I'm trying to query from.

I tested in Postman, and was able to retrieve the data I wanted.

Query:

```
query {
    pages(name: "Index") {
        data {
            name
            title
            subtitle
            text
            meta_title
            meta_description
        }
    }

    featured: posts(featured: true, first: 1) {
        data {
            title
            summary
            text
        }
    }

    posts(first: 6) {
        data {
            title
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{
    "data": {
        "pages": {
            "data": [
                {
                    "name": "Index",
                    "title": "The Beloved's Blog",
                    "subtitle": "So you also are complete through your union with Christ, who is the head over every ruler and authority.\r\nCol 2:10 NLT",
                    "text": null,
                    "meta_title": "The Beloved's Blog",
                    "meta_description": "A blog I maintain to store the personal testimonies and revelations I have."
                }
            ]
        },
        "featured": {
            "data": [
                {
                    "title": "Jesus Made Us Unique",
                    "summary": "I’m sure most of us have felt pressured by the definitions of what it means to be “good in something”. It could come from the world, from our friends and families, or even from us. Eg. what it takes to be a good employee, a good person, a good mum/dad,...",
                    "text": "I’m sure most of us have felt pressured by the definitions of what it means to be “good in something”. It could come from the world, from our friends and families, or even from us. Eg. what it takes to be a good employee, a good person, a good mum/dad, or even a good Christian. “Oh, to be a good Christian, you need to be this; you need to be that. You need to do this; you need to do that.”\r\n\r\nBut we must remember that Jesus made us all unique. He has already put in each of us the gifts and grace to achieve and accomplish our callings. While we should be open to feedback, don’t let them define your identity. Whether or not you fit into the definitions of what it means to be good, you are forever loved and righteous in Jesus. \r\n\r\nEspecially when one desires to live for Jesus, one will face opposition from the devil. He wants to stop you from living a Jesus-life. So he will do all he can to oppose you; from negative thoughts and feelings to surrounding you with jealous people. \r\n\r\nJust like in this passage. When David was about to face Goliath, Saul tried to get David to wear his armour. Saul’s trust was in his armour, while David’s trust was in the Lord. From here you could see Saul subtly trying to put down David’s faith. But David resisted by taking off the armour and going in his anointing as a shepherd and not a warrior. \r\n\r\nHave you ever felt pressured before to be someone you are not? Run to Jesus. Let HIM tell you about you. Jesus is with you, and He has made each of you unique. Each one of you is precious and valuable to Him. He loves you immensely; every part of you… including your quirks!\r\n\r\nHope this has blessed you. Be blessed and stay blessed in Jesus’ amen."
                }
            ]
        },
        "posts": {
            "data": [
                {
                    "title": "We Are Under the New Covenant"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Jesus Helps Me in My Coding"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Thank You Jesus for Your Productivity and Wisdom in My Life"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Jesus Made Us Unique"
                },
                {
                    "title": "A Week of Rest & Acceleration"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Review Went Well and Received an Increment"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Finally found what I needed on this [page](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/third-party-graphql/).

Posting this in-case anyone else runs into the same issues as I did.